# Android studio - how to show implementation in window ( like documentation)

Tags: android-studio

people. I have a question. Sometimes accidentally a window appears above some method with it's implementation. So I want to understand is there a shortcut for showing implementation of a method above the method(in new small window - like this when studio shows documentation) ? In my opinion it will be convenient to know it, because in that way it is not necessary to go to implementation and to go up and down in the code. Unfortunately I couldn't find it when I try to google it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

here you go the cheatsheet
[hotkeys](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much ! Accidentally I see "Ctrl + Shift + I Open quick definition lookup" . That's I was looking for.
Thank you again !

Comment: Please add the important stuff from your link to the answer. (in this case the shortcut to show the method above the method..) Because once that site changes, the link may no longer be available and thus this answer useless.